# Let's Play a Game

Tags: riddle

I am a game character.
I like money.
I am on lots of cards.
In the game I am in, you pick either a ship, dog, wheelbarrow, hat, car, or thimble.
Who am I?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because trivia is not a puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> **Uncle Pennybags** from Monopoly. He is also known as **Mr. Monopoly**

Comment: this has got to be the fastest answer ever

Comment: @dma1324 naah... [Deusovi](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi) have the monopoly over the fastest answers

Comment: Where I live we call him Mister Monopoly but YES! Correct.

Comment: @manshu I barely missed it... Now I guess I have to check Puzzling.SE more frequently to keep my reputation.

Comment: I've always known him as UP but recently saw him referred to as MM in a promotion at a local grocery store, so maybe it's just an alternate name they're tossing around?

Comment: @feelinferrety now you know his another name...it's Milburn Pennybags